# Convert Nested mysql query to knex query

Tags: knex.js

Beginner knex user here. I have an nested sql query that looks like this:

```
SELECT
    col1,
    col2,
    ...
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        detailed.*,
        t2.col1,
        t2.col2
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            col1,
            col2,
            ... 
        FROM
            (
            SELECT
                ...
            FROM table_1
            ) sorted
        ) detailed
    JOIN table_2 AS t2
    ) summary
JOIN (...) 
GROUP BY
   col1
```

What I did was store the subqueries each in a string variable then "feed" it into the main query like so:

```
let subquery1 = `SELECT ...`;
let subquery2 = `SELECT ... FROM (${subquery1}) sorted`;
let subquery3 = `SELECT ... FROM (${subquery2}) detailed JOIN table2 as t2 ...`;

qb.select(col1, col2, ...)
.from(knex.raw(`({$subquery3}) summary`))
.join(...)
.groupBy('col1');
```

It looks short here but it's actually quite a long code. I'm wondering if there is a more knex-like approach to this kind of query. Would love to hear your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

It was all in the [docs](https://knexjs.org/guide/query-builder.html#as). I just didn't look hard enough.

```
qb.select('col1', 'col2')
  .from(function(){
       this.select('detailed.*', 't2.col1', 't2.col2')
           .from(function(){
                this.select('col1', 'col2', ...)
                    .from(function(){
                         this.select(...)
                             .from('table_1 as t1')
                             .as('sorted')
                    })
                    .as('detailed')
           })
           .join('table_2 as t2')
           .as('summary')
   })
  .join(...)
  .groupBy('col1');
```